# Vuetify change style of specified scrollbar of v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Why I can't change the scroll of this `v-select`?

I want to customized the scrollbar of my v-select.

In the sample below, I do the normal way, But there's no use.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['Foo1', 'Bar1', 'Fizz1', 'Buzz1', 'Foo2', 'Bar2', 'Fizz2', 'Buzz2', 'Foo3', 'Bar3', 'Fizz3', 'Buzz3'],
  }),
})
```

```css
/* SCROLL STYLE FOR V-SELECT */
#selectScroll::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 10px;
}
#selectScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
}
#selectScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background-color: #b85125;
}
#selectScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color: #962d00;
}



/* SCROLL STYLE FOR V-CARD */
#cardScroll::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 10px;
}
#cardScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
}
#cardScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background-color: #1976d2;
}
#cardScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color: #1976d2;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
          <v-select
             id="selectScroll"
            :items="items"
            label="Change Scrollbar"
          ></v-select>

          <v-select
            :items="items"
            label="No Scrollbar Change"
          ></v-select>
    
      <v-card id="cardScroll" style="height:200px;overflow-y:auto">
        <v-card-text v-for="test in 20" :key="test">
         {{ test }}
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I change the scrollbar of v-select with the id `selectScroll` only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From v-select docs (menu-props):

> Pass props through to the v-menu component. Accepts either a string
> for boolean props menu-props="auto, overflowY", or an object
> :menu-props="{ auto: true, overflowY: true }"

From v-menu docs (content-class)

```html
<template>
    <v-select
        :menu-props="{ contentClass: 'selectScroll'}"
        :items="items"
        label="Change Scrollbar"
    />
</template>
```

```css
<style>
    /* SCROLL STYLE FOR V-SELECT */
    .selectScroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 10px;
    }

    .selectScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
    }

    .selectScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #b85125;
    }

    .selectScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background-color: #962d00;
    }
</style>
```